# Creating a folder on fileSystem dynamics ax

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

i need to check if a folder exists in a particular location,if not then create that folder and save the appropriate file there.How can i acheive this using X++.

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check folder existence you can use `WinApi::pathExists`,
to create one `WinApi::createDirectory` or `WinApi::createDirectoryPath`:

```
str  path = 'C:\\tmp\\aFolder';
;
if (!WinApi::pathExists(path))
{
    WinApi::createDirectoryPath(path);
}
```

I have no idea what is meant by "the appropriate file", but have a look at the `TextIO`, `BinaryIO` or the other *IO classes.